# Paginate Elasticseach aggregator result

Tags: pagination, elasticsearch

I want to paginate with 'size' and 'from' attributes Elasticseach aggregator query.

Is this possible ?

Currently I only know the size attribute = 0 for unlimited result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature for pagination in aggregation is not implemented yet. You could use the combination on size and exclude feature in facet.