# How to Use pagination (size and from) in elastic search aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, aggregation

How to Use pagination (size and from) in elasticsearch aggregation , I used Size and from in agreggition it,s throw exception for exmaple.
I wanna  query like?

GET /index/nameorder/_search

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "projectId": "10057"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "purchasedDate": {
                        "from": "2012-02-05T00:00:00",
                        "to": "2015-02-11T23:59:59"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_a": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "promocode",
                "size": 40,
                "from": 40
            },
            "aggs": {
                "TotalPrice": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "subtotalPrice"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isnt this elastic search ? Y are u tagging it as mongodb

Comment: possible duplicate of [Paginate Elasticseach aggregator result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865687/paginate-elasticseach-aggregator-result)

Comment: yea It,s elastic search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregation + sorting +pagination in elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776582/aggregation-sorting-pagination-in-elastic-search)

Answer (score 6):

As of now , this feature is not supported.

There is a bug on this , but its still in discuss mode.

Issue - https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/4915

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the only valid answer as of now. +1.

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement pagination on top of aggregation in Elasticsearch, you need to do as follows.

1. Define the size of each batch.
2. Run [cardinality count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)
3. Then according to cardinality define partition =  (Cardinality count / size )(this size must be smaller than fetch size)
4. now you can iterate over the partitions using [partition filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-) - Please note size must be big enough cause the results are not equally splitted between the buckets.