# How to paginate the aggregations in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query which uses a sub-aggregation to fetch the product name grouped by the manufacturer. I am getting results fine but I need to paginate them. There are some results which do not show up because of default size.

```
GET product/_search
{
  "fields": ["name","maName"],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "name.autocomplete": {
            "query": "cro",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        }
      },
      "must_not": {"term": {"source": "old"}}
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "group_agg": {
      "terms": {"field": "productGroupName.raw"},
      "aggregations": {
        "manufacturer_name": {
          "terms": { "field": "maName.raw" },
          "aggs": {
            "top_products": {
              "top_hits": {
                "_source": ["name", "maName", "PRICE"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The pagination has to there for the aggregated result. Can I specify any limit somewhere? I think that can be easily done with the top hits, but how about the whole aggregation result?

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915) being heavily discussed and it's still not implemented yet.

Comment: Can I have all the buckets returned, somehow, if I cannot paginate?

Comment: Yes, you can use a big `size` setting in your `terms` aggregation that you know will return all your buckets. The default size if not specified is 10.

Comment: Is it suggested to use a big `size`? I have let's say around max of 200-250 rows for any term (ex: `cro`) and they can easily fit in some 35-40 buckets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paginate Elasticseach aggregator result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865687/paginate-elasticseach-aggregator-result)